# Firebase Cloud Function trigger

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

As I know currently Cloud Functions doesn't support triggering functions from Firebase.

For now I'm planing to use an basic Engine instance to trigger the functions based on the queue.

Is this the right way to go? or should I trigger the cloud function directly from the clients device after the data is inserted in the db?

thank you

Comment: You may want to consider [firebase-queue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-queue) running on your instance to help trigger Cloud Functions -- you can write to the queue from the client and then send data along via the server-side listener.

Comment: Thank you Frank for the suggestion, I'm already testing it.

Answer (score 6):

Cloud Functions for Firebase was just launched today! You can use the SDK to trigger cloud functions from your Firebase database, storage bucket, authentication, and analytics events. https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/